# Without passing Request parameter How Can i get the Logged in Username in django

Tags: python, django

i make a class in a **py file** in my **django project**. In this i need the **logged in person's username**. in **views.py** file, every function i pass **request** perameter, so that i could easily get the logged username. but in other py file i make a class, and there **how can i get the logged user**??? Thanks.

in class, i can not pass the request perametar. so i can not call **requset.user**. **how can i get the logged user**???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use sessions to get the logged in user as follows: `request.session.get('_auth_user_id')`

In your class you may pass the request as an argument.